# Extending a numpy.matrix gives __new__ and __class__ issues?

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to quickly write a Points class, where each column of the underlying 2D `numpy.matrix` is assigned to an attribute
such that I can write stuff like this easily:

```py
points      = Points(np.mat(np.ones((2,3))), names=["a","b","c"])
points.a    = points.b + points.c
points["a"] = points["b"] + points["c"]
```

I came up with this kind of "monkey patch"

```py
class Points(np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix):

  def __new__(cls, *args, names=[], **kwargs):
      o = np.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
      o.__class__ = Points
      return o

  def __init__(self, *args, names=[], **kwargs):
      # Set the attribute self.<pointName> 
      # to a reference of the corresponding column
      for i,name in enumerate(names):
          self.__setattr__(name, self[:,i])
```

I was wondering if there is a better method of doing a bruteforce `o.__class__ = Points`. 
I need to do this because the `Points.__init__` does not get called since, `type(o) != Points`.

The whole class is here 
https://gist.github.com/gabyx/9392992d11bf8550e44002ac7f1ecaaf

Comment: Why not just use [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) or [NumPys structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)? These do have this column and row accessing operations already.

Comment: Record arrays (np.rec.array) will give you the dot notation for field access.

Comment: I thought so too , but structured arrays are hard to manipulate, lets say easily transform all points by a matrix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, with `numpy.version.full_version == '1.8.0'` in Python 3.5.1:

```
import numpy

class Points(numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix):
    def __new__(subtype, data, names=[], **kwargs):
        tmp = super(Point, subtype).__new__(subtype, data, **kwargs)

        for i, name in zip(range(tmp.shape[0]), names):
            tmp.__setattr__('point_{}'.format(name), tmp[i])

        return tmp


arr = numpy.arange(6).reshape((-1, 3))

a = Points(arr, names='abc')
print(a)
print(a.point_a, a.point_b)
```

Looks like there's no need for `Points.__init__` at all as all the arguments are passed directly to `Points.__new__`, and then to `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix.__new__`. Moreover, `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix.__init__` ignores all the arguments provided. However, you could move the `__setattr__` logic to `Points.__init__` if you want.

Comment: Why not `for row, name in zip(tmp, names)`?

Comment: @Eric, right, that looks better, I was just copying from the OP's code

Comment: The problem here is that the returned `tmp` is of type : `'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'` which is odd. and I dont understand why

Comment: That's not a problem: in order to create an instance of `Point`, you should initialize `numpy.blah.matrix` first. And then, after this instance is _created_, it can be initialized with `__init__`, which isn't needed here.

Comment: sure its a problem, if I define more functions on `Points` they are not accessible

Comment: @Gabriel, they actually are. At least, with my setup... What Python version are you using?